# How to get a textfield in android in this format?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I need a text field like this: ""E-mail *Example@gmail.com*""

The above whole thing has to be in the text field and when we enter data in the field, the E-mail must be present and the hint: Example@gmail.com must go.

I could get the word E-mail above the text field but how to get it inside it and let it be there always unlike the hint?

Comment: `editText.setHint("Example@gmail.com");`

Comment: Ya I could set the hint but I want the word E-mail to be present inside the text field always

Comment: Why don't you use a TextView for text "E-mail"?

Comment: how is the user supposed to read what they write if the text is always there?

Comment: The field which we will be entering continues after the word E-mail.......it is like this:
BEFORE ENTERING: "E-mail *Example@gmail.com*"
AFTER ENTERING : "E-mail george@gmail.com"

Comment: I guess what you want is a textfield "Email " and an EditText with a hint "Example@gmail.com" ... the user cannot enter text in a textfield - therefore you'll always have to use an EditText or similar

Comment: @axel yeah exactly I want it that way. but the textfield: E-mail must also be inside the entering area

Comment: @axel So in the EditText how do I keep the field "Email" fixed i.e. always present

Comment: @user1424394: Why? That's completely counterintuitive to every user experience...ever. The standard, accepted method pretty much everywhere is as axel and Shaiful suggest: a label (TextView) on the left, and an editable text field (EditText) to the right of it.

Comment: @kcoppock See this: http://opensolution.org/Quick.Cms/docs_v3.x/lib/exe/fetch.php?w=&h=&cache=cache&media=admin_logowanie_en.jpg

I want the word Login and Password inside the white field

Comment: doesn't sound like the best UI design to me, but if that's what you want you could try to extend EditText (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/EditText.java) and try to replace the string that is displayed to the user (worth a shot, but I'm not sure if it's possible)

Comment: @user1424394: We understand what you *want*, we're explaining that it's a bad idea.

Comment: @kcoppock ya I know but what to do....my employer wants it that way :/

Comment: @user1424394: I'd suggest explaining that it's a bad idea, and why, and provide counter-examples of established products that do it differently. Oh, and you're more than welcome to refer him to this thread, where I say: "It's a terrible idea, providing a poor user experience and going against the expected behavior of the Android platform."

Comment: Hahaaa sure...I'll get fired :D

Comment: Anyone with a solution to do this?

Comment: Maybe I've just had decent employers so far, but I've never understood the "fear" mentality people have of respectfully opposing an idea from an employer, when they have reasonable evidence that they have a better way. Sure, maybe he's an unreasonable employer and he'll reject the idea, but at least you could say you tried. Anyway, this comment thread is too long as it is, so I'll take my leave. Good luck.

Comment: Try putting a TextView to the left of an EditText, as others have suggested, and styling them so they appear to be one field. (Same background color, no space between them, etc.) I'm not sure how configurable the styling of EditText is (you'd need to get rid of the border around the text being edited); it may or may not be possible.

Comment: I've never seen anything like what you mention, it seems useless, Hint is the most elegant solution that android can offer.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you have a little layout with a Label denoting that this field is for e-mail. No need to have it permanently embedded.